# Getting the next element with the same class during the page scroll with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a page I have 10 elements with the same class name:

```
<span class="simpleclass">text</span>
```

What I'm trying to do is - go to the next element with class "simpleclass" when the page is scrolled. That means that for the first time when I scroll the page I need to get a reference to the second span with class "simpleclass" on the page, etc. Could anybody help me to figure out how this can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a global variable for tracking the current `span`:

```
var currentSpan = 1;
```

Then, whenever the page is scrolled, you can get the next `span` and increment the `currentSpan` variable:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var span = $("span.simpleclass").eq(currentSpan);
    currentSpan++;
});
```

Comment: Please note that when scroll event fires your `span` variable after first scroll will be `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Hand craft :)
http://jsfiddle.net/TK3dd/7/

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var length = $('.simpleclass').length;
    var off = $('.simpleclass').css('height').replace('px','');
    var _tmp = Math.ceil(Math.abs(window.scrollY)/parseInt(off));
    _tmp = _tmp > (length-1) ? (length-1) : _tmp;
    console.log( $('.simpleclass:eq('+_tmp+')') );
})​
```